# how to map different prots inside a docker service with traefik?

Tags: wordpress, docker, traefik, bitnami

I am setting up a wordpress site using bitnami images, these exposes unpriviledged port 8181 and 8443 , so I would like to map port 443 to the service container port 8443,
I've tried with expose: [8443]  and defining the loadbalance port without success.
it is not very clear if I have to define the target port in the service or in the middleware.

here is my traefik definition

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  traefik:
    external: true

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.5"
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    command:
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=mail@me.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - traefik
    volumes:
      - "letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
```

And the service (relevant parts)

```
  wordpress:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/wordpress-nginx:5
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/bitnami/wordpress
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      ....
      ....
      NGINX_HTTP_PORT_NUMBER: 8181
      NGINX_HTTPS_PORT_NUMBER: 8443
    networks:
      - traefik
      - backend
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress.rule=Host(`domain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress.middlewares=redirect-to-https@docker"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress-secured.rule=Host(`domain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress-secured.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress-secured.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress-secured.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found the solution: I need to configure the loadbalancer server port to tell traefik where service is listening to

```
services:
  wordpress:
    labels:
       - 'traefik.http.services.wordpress-secured.LoadBalancer.server.port=8181'
```